# Preserving Recovery Partitions

Tags: linux, windows-8, partitioning

I've just bought a *Samsung 530U3C* notebook with *Windows 8* preinstalled. I would like it to run some *Linux* distribution but at the same time to preserve recovery partitions so that I could hard reset it in case of emergency.

I've checked partitions states just after first boot and that's what I've noticed

```
/dev/sda1    Windows Re Tools
/dev/sda2    SYSTEM
/dev/sda3    
/dev/sda4    
/dev/sda5    SAMSUNG_REC2
`/dev/sda6    SAMSUNG_REC


/dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb2
```

My question are:

1. What **partitions need to be preserved** to be able to use F4
   recovery during startup?
2. I assume that `/dev/sdb` is in fact an SSD used for ExpressCache,
   right?
3. When recovering using F4 do I have to **provide the exact same
   partition table** as now?

Looking forward to any answers.

Comment: You could use a linux live-cd and boot from cd and open all partitions to see what content is stored on which disk/partition. That way you can find out which disk is the HDD and the SSD. In addition you will see the Windows partition and your personal data drives. But that's just a first idea. Try to figure out what's stored to the partitions.

Comment: 1 Can be crossed out, as 3 doubles as a answer to both, yes you will need the exact same partition table, I recommend you backup either the entire drive or at least the MBR although from what I've seen you can run into multiple errors if you don't have a exact copy of the entire drive, I'll see if I can find the link to a question with similar info on it.